# Get Data From Dynamically Created EditTexts In A Different Activity

Tags: android, dynamic, android-edittext, textview

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated. I am trying to take data which will be input by the user into dynamically generated EditTexts in one activity and put the data into TextViews in another activity. While it is true I found similar questions elsewhere on this website, I couldn't solve the problem myself so I figured there's something in my code that will jump out at someone. Keep in mind that I've tried to accomplish this in multiple ways so the code might be ugly because I got frustrated and kept trying to implement more and more to make it work.

Activity A (a number of EditTexts are created based on a number the user inputs, and I need to take what the user types in the EditTexts, perhaps in an array???? and move it to Activity B.

```
    final Button submitButton = new Button(this);
    submitButton.setText("Submit");
    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(ChoiceMaker.this, Randomizer.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            setContentView(R.layout.randomizer);

        }
    });


    btnCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public List<EditText> strings;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            List<EditText> allEds = null;
            if (edtNoCreate.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                try {
                    lnrDynamicEditTextHolder.removeAllViews();
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                int length = Integer.parseInt(edtNoCreate.getText().toString());
                EditText editText;
                allEds = new ArrayList<EditText>();

                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    editText = new EditText(ChoiceMaker.this);
                    allEds.add(editText);
                    editText.setId(i + 1);
                    editText.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    editText.setHint("Possible choice " + (i + 1));
                    editText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#c0b1ff"));
                    editText.setTextSize(38);
                    lnrDynamicEditTextHolder.addView(editText);


                }


                LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.choiceMakerLayout);
                layout.addView(submitButton);
                submitButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

                String[] strings = new String[allEds.size()];

                for(int i=0; i < allEds.size(); i++){
                    strings[i] = allEds.get(i).getText().toString();
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(ChoiceMaker.this, Randomizer.class);
                intent.putExtra("strings", strings);

            }

        }

    }
```

Activity B

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.randomizer);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String[] stringArray = intent.getStringArrayExtra("strings");
    int textViewCount = 10;

    TextView[] textViewArray = new TextView[textViewCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < textViewCount; i++) {
        textViewArray[i] = new TextView(this);
        textViewArray[i].setText(stringArray);



}}
```

Comment: If it's any help I am given the error of a null pointer and when I debug it shows the array as null. I believe the data may never even get into the array in Activity A.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need to track the views you are creating with the "tags", 
while creating the views do it like below,

```
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    editText = new EditText(ChoiceMaker.this);
                    allEds.add(editText);

                    editText.setTag(i); //mark this step

                    editText.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    editText.setHint("Possible choice " + (i + 1));
                    editText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#c0b1ff"));
                    editText.setTextSize(38);
                    lnrDynamicEditTextHolder.addView(editText);
                }
```

and then whenever you want to start another activity to pass data, eg:on button click,

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < lnrDynamicEditTextHolder.getChildCount(); i++) {
                            arrayList.add(((EditText) lnrDynamicEditTextHolder.findViewWithTag(i)).getText().toString());
                        }

                        Intent intent = new Intent(ChoiceMaker.this, Randomizer.class);
                        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("strings", arrayList);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
```